# bmon : No working input module found

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line, command, debian

I'm trying to use the bmon command on my Ubuntu Server but without success on my OVH VPS (Works well on other servers)

> $ bmon
>
> No working input module found

Something to pass in param ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working fine :

> $ bmon -i proc

-i for input mod
proc (Linux)
Provides interface statistics on Linux using the proc filesystem (/proc/net/dev). It is one of the fallback input modules on Linux and will work on nearly every Linux kernel version.

See [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bmon) ;)